# Difficulty while coding a Vigenère cipher

Tags: vb.net, vigenere

I am attempting to follow a tutorial on how to make a Vigenère cipher.
However I am encountering an error when inputting any key as it gives me an error saying it's outside the range.

Can someone please help me?

```
Function VigNere(ByVal Txtstring As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal encrypt As Boolean) As String
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim temp As String = ""
    Dim j As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To Txtstring.Length
        If Char.IsLetter(key(j)) Then
            If Txtstring(i) <> " " And Char.IsLetter(Txtstring(i)) Then
                If j = key.Length Then
                    j = 0
                End If
                temp += key(j)
                j += 1
            Else
                temp += Txtstring(i)
            End If
        Else
            j += 1
            If (j >= key.Length) Then
                j = 0
            End If
            i -= 1
        End If
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To Txtstring.Length - 1
        Dim N As Integer
        Dim NewAscii As Integer
        If Char.IsLetter(Txtstring(i)) Then
            If Char.IsLower(temp(i)) Then
                N = Asc(temp(i)) - Asc("a")
            ElseIf Char.IsUpper(temp(i)) Then
                N = Asc(temp(i)) - Asc("A")
            End If
            If encrypt Then
                NewAscii = N + Asc(Txtstring(i))
            Else
                NewAscii = 26 - N + Asc(Txtstring(i))

            End If
            If (NewAscii > Asc("z") And Char.IsLower(Txtstring(i))) Or (NewAscii > Asc("Z") And Char.IsUpper(Txtstring(i))) Then
                NewAscii -= 26
            End If
        Else
            NewAscii = Asc(Txtstring(i))

        End If
        result += Chr(NewAscii)

    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Your first For loop doesn't have the -1 at the end. `For i As Integer = 0 To Txtstring.Length` Just add the -1

Comment: The second loop looks ok (it has redundant parts, though). The first is undefined. You should build the key phrase, using the key multiplied by `[Message Length] / [Key Length] + [Remainder]`. But it appears it would only pass through when the keyphrase is already complete. If just the key is provided, it will count past the key length, doing actually nothing.

Comment: (I just noticed that a (very small) piece was missing)- The first loop could be: `dim position = 0 dim keyphrase As Char() = new Char(Txtstring.Length - 1) {} For i as Integer = 0 To Txtstring.Length - 1 keyphrase(i) = key(position) position += If(position < key.Length - 1, 1, -position) next`